# Tried to edit a question to format the code as a code block

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I tried to put code in one question in a `codeblock`, but it didn't allow me saying I can do only single spaces for six characters or something like that. What does that mean?

Comment: Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

Edits must be at least 6 non-space characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

Comment: nope actually the code was aligned with the question and I tried to seperate it out. thats it.

Comment: Is that the message that you got?

Comment: Yeah it popped up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you suggest an edit to someone's post (i.e. you don't have editing priviliges yet), you need to make at least 6 non-whitespace characters of change. Adding four spaces to indent the code isn't enough to make the edit. Try to see if there's anything else you can do to make the post even better--maybe clarify a title, fix grammar, etc.