# Can minimum character limit or reputation threshold for suggested edits be changed locally (per site)?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, privileges, character-limit

Is it possible for moderators to request changing of the minimum character limit for suggested edits for a particular site? Or is it at least possible to lower the rep required for edits?

I am asking this in connection with discussions on sites supporting MathJax/TeX, as changing one character in TeX can often affect a large portion of a post (e.g. unpaired `{` `}`, forgotten `$`, etc.).

- http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216/minimum-suggested-edit-length at meta.math
- [Minimum character of an edit](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/316/minimum-character-of-an-edit) at meta.mathoverflow

EDIT: Just in case this issue comes up again in the future, I should perhaps clarify that this post was not intended as [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). (Which is why it is not tagged as such.) If was merely an inquiry whether changes like this are currently possible or not.

Comment: You actually have a very good point, which would be better served on Meta.TeX.SE as a feature request.

Comment: @Emrakul AFAIK TeX.SE does not have MathJax support. [Tag-wiki for MathJax](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/mathjax/info) lists the pages with Mathjax support, although the info might be not entirely up to date.

Comment: Er, sorry. Meant to say _Math_ meta

Comment: Even though the question was motivated by problems with MathJax edits (which have been already discussed on two different per-site metas), I think the questions whether SE network is able/willing to change some settings per-site is more on topic here.

Comment: This is true. It reminds me of an IRC saying, though: "Don't ask to ask, just ask!" in that you may have more progress just asking for the limit to be changed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the threshold needs to depend on the site. Rather, the issue here is that mathematics packs a lot of meaning in a single character. Therefore, I propose to amend the feature request to allowing any edit that affects MathJax portions of a post. That would only have effect on sites that have MathJax, but it would be a feature of the MathJax code rather than a per-site configuration.

Comment: Yes, this was one of suggestions given in the [feature request from meta.math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216/minimum-suggested-edit-length) I've linked above.

Comment: This is also a bit similar to the suggestion here (although it is for code blocks rather than MathJax): [Allow under 6 character changes if they are inside code tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76891)

Answer (score -2):

> I am asking this in connection with discussions on sites supporting MathJax/TeX, as changing one character in TeX can often affect a large portion of a post (e.g. unpaired { }, forgotten $, etc.).

And on sites with code blocks (e.g. Stack Overflow, Programmers, Code Golf, etc.), an incorrectly placed or omitted backtick can break formatting. So can four spaces missing in front of a line.

And on sites with hyperlinks (e.g. all of them), one or two invalid characters can break an entire link.

And on and on. There are occasions where changing 6 or fewer characters is a valid edit and can make a substantial improvement to a post.

But changing the rules so that people can freely submit edits of only one or two characters that are almost trivial by definition is a bad idea. Even if it only applies to a particular site, it is still a global setting that applies to all edits submitted on that site.

I don't really see this as a problem. Fix the problems you see. Even if the *main* problem is a minor fix that comes in under six characters, [dream bigger](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91763/153008). Find something else that is wrong, and fix that too. Rare is the post where there is absolutely nothing else that can be improved.

Related:

- [Remove trivial edit restriction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82893/remove-trivial-edit-restriction)
- [How to overcome "Edits must be at least 6 characters"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters)
- [Are we discouraged from fixing typos and misspellings on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77233/are-we-discouraged-from-fixing-typos-and-misspellings-on-stack-exchange-sites)
- [Allow smaller edits for everyone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82943/allow-smaller-edits-for-everyone)
- [Reconsider the restrictions on editing an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134113/reconsider-the-restrictions-on-editing-an-answer)
- [Change this behavior to allow for spelling corrections and the like: "Edits must be at least 6 characters"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82534/change-this-behavior-to-allow-for-spelling-corrections-and-the-like-edits-must)
- [Why should edits be at least six non-space characters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140288/why-should-edits-be-at-least-six-non-space-characters)
- [Edits under 6 characters should be allowed if in a hyperlink URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85326/edits-under-6-characters-should-be-allowed-if-in-a-hyperlink-url)
- [Can't create a mark-down link when editing an existing answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115830/cant-create-a-mark-down-link-when-editing-an-existing-answer)
- [Cannot suggest a single-character fix for a typo in a URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106845/cannot-suggest-a-single-character-fix-for-a-typo-in-a-url)
- [pure code formatting, to enhance a question, is impossible (without 2k rep)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87200/pure-code-formatting-to-enhance-a-question-is-impossible-without-2k-rep)
- [Test for "at least 6 non-space characters" stopped a perfectly good edit from being done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105576/test-for-at-least-6-non-space-characters-stopped-a-perfectly-good-edit-from-be)
- [Tried to edit a question to format the code as a code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121690/tried-to-edit-a-question-to-format-the-code-as-a-code-block)
- [correction with less than 6 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160238/correction-with-less-than-6-characters)
- [Can't fix link in answer because it needs minimum chars to edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126099/cant-fix-link-in-answer-because-it-needs-minimum-chars-to-edit)
- Sorry, I got bored of this.

Comment: You have a lot of links to other people pointing out that this is a stupid rule, always has been a stupid rule, and always will be a stupid rule. So, yeah, it's a stupid rule. So what can we do about it?

Comment: Hmm. I'm afraid you missed the point @TRiG. I don't think it's a stupid rule.

Comment: Oh, I saw what you were saying. My point, such as it was, was that the links you've posted don't support your point.